# Search tags on a specific user profile (Instagram)

Tags: database, instagram, instagram-api

As a part of my yearly career goals at work I decided I would try and tackle a simple database-tyoe webpage.

I was curious if there was a way for me to search tags on a specific user profile (Instagram)?

My idea is to code a single-page webpage that uses a search function to find tagged posts on a specific users Instagram account and display the results. Is this possible? Tips or resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no Instagram API endpoint that will allow you to retrieve all hashtagged photos for a specific user. You will need to retrieve all the users posts using the `user` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/ endpoint and then filter the results.